# UIStoryboard Segue Shuffle

Tags: ipad, ios7, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

New project, using storyboards for the first time. So many things I did easily with nibs is frustrating me to no end.

I want to be able to hop around and shuffle my views at will. I have figured out unwinds and pushes and all goes well as long as I continue linearly forward in the storyboard path. At some point I want to hop laterally back to a view that may already be somewhere on the stack, or not. This doesn't seem to work as expected.

Using UINavigationController. 
Say, at one point I have 3 different views moving forward. I push one of them and go about business along that "fork". Now at some point I want to hop over to one of the other 3 paths at that fork without backtracking  through the stack.

Previously, I might just instantiate the correct view controller from nib, push, then remove the view controllers from the stack that are between the "fork" and the current view. Or, if that view controller was already on the stack, I could shuffle it around by manipulating the array directly.

How can I do this with segues?

I tried making segues to and from each of the three view controllers at the fork. What a mess. I keep getting errors, segue not found, when I know they are there. I tried "replace" segues, they didn't work as I expected. Not to mention my storyboard looks like a spiderweb.

I don't like to be stuck in the old ways. If storyboards are the future, I want to be on board sooner rather than later but I could have been so much further along if I'd stuck with what I know. Any storyboard wizards willing to school me with suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered, my solution turned out to be abandoning the navigation controller entirely and use a variation of the method detailed here by Michael Luton:

http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

If anyone has need for this, I can say that it works very nicely and is quite simple to implement.